# Getting a curve intersection between a PLY point cloud (edges and faces) and a plan

Tags: geometry

What's the most easy way to get the **curve of the intersection** between a 3D model (described by a PLY file) and a plane?

Example: The intersection between a plan passing by the center of a sphere and the sphere gives me a circle or at least a cloud point looking like a circle.

The problem is that the planes can be anywhere, so it can pass by some of the point cloud (contained in the PLY) or pass between them and only cut a face of the object. You can see in the picture above an example of a PLY shape, only described by a point cloud with connections between them (edges or arbitrary polygon faces).

[Dodecahedron PLY example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdQ5j.png)

Does **Octave** have a built-in functionality to do so?

Comment: Subtract a point on the plane from each point on the point cloud, then scalar product with normal vector to the plane, will  split into vectors which have a positive and a negative scalar product depending on the side of the plane.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you said. Does your solution manage faces/edges ? Because that's the tricky part I don't have a point cloud but edges and faces. I should be more explicit in my post.

Comment: No, sorry my approach only gives on which side of the plane each point in the point cloud is.

Comment: But if you know which points limit an edge or a face you can do logical computations to decide if the whole edge/face is on the same side or not. If not all of them belonging to the same edge/face have the same sign of that scalar product then the edge (or face) will be split by the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PLY file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)) defines vertices and (polygon) faces. This means the intersection(s) between a plane and the polygons defined in a PLY file are polylines (or polygons). Although not explicitly declared so, I do believe the vertices defining each face are listed in order, so that consecutive vertices are connected with an edge (and so are the first and last vertex listed for a face).

Whether there are Octave functions to do this, I do not know.

The algorithm to determine the intersection can be split in two parts. First, you find the line segments for each polygon face that intersects the plane. Then, you connect the line segments to form the polylines or polygons (although if you only do this for visual purposes, you can skip this.)

The intersection between a plane and a planar polygon is either empty (no intersection), one or more points (if the plane passes through extremal vertices only), or one or more line segments. If the polygon is convex (say, a triangle), then the intersection is either empty, a point, or a line segment.

If you define the plane using its normal vector $\vec{n}$, and minimum signed distance to origin $d$, point $p$ is on the plane if and only if
$$\vec{n} \cdot \vec{p} + d = 0$$
If you have three consecutive vertices in the polygon, $\vec{v}_0$, $\vec{v}_1$, and $\vec{v}_2$, you can calculate
$$\vec{n} = ( \vec{v}_2 - \vec{v}_1 ) \times ( \vec{v}_0 - \vec{v}_1 )$$
and
$$d = -\vec{n} \cdot \vec{v}_0 \; ( = -\vec{n} \cdot \vec{v}_1 = -\vec{n} \cdot \vec{v}_2 )$$

Convex face polygons are trivial to deal with, compared to concave face polygons. So, let's assume that at this point, you decompose face polygons with more than three vertices into triangles (via [polygon triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation)).

Each triangle can either not intersect with the plane at all, intersect with the plane at a single point (at one of the vertices), or the intersection can be a line segment. We find the intersection line segments, and if more than one are found (among all the faces), we merge the connected ones into a polygon. If the object or objects defined by the face polygons are closed, then the overall intersections are also closed; either empty, point(s), or closed polygon(s).

To find if and where a triangle defined by vertices $\vec{v}_0$, $\vec{v}_1$, and $\vec{v}_2$ intersects a plane, calculate
$$\begin{array}{c}
s_0 = \vec{n} \cdot \vec{v}_0 - d \\
s_1 = \vec{n} \cdot \vec{v}_1 - d \\
s_2 = \vec{n} \cdot \vec{v}_2 - d \end{array}$$
i.e. signed distance between each vertex and the plane. Then,

- If $s_0$, $s_1$, and $s_2$ are all nonzero and have the same sign, there is no intersection.
- If one of $s_0$, $s_1$, and $s_2$ is zero, and the other two are nonzero and have the same sign, then the plane intersects the triangle at a point, at the vertex corresponding to the zero.
- If two of $s_0$, $s_1$, and $s_2$ are zero, and the third is nonzero, the plane intersects the triangle at the edge between the two vertices corresponding to the zeros.
- If all three of $s_0$, $s_1$, and $s_2$ are zero, the entire triangle is on the intersection plane. (If the object defined by the triangular faces is closed, you do not need to include these edges in the intersection.)
- If one of $s_0$, $s_1$, and $s_2$ is zero, and the other two have different signs, then the plane intersects the triangle in a line segment. Let's say $s_0 = 0$, $s_1 \lt 0 $, and $s_2 \gt 0$. Then, the intersection line has one endpoint at vertex $\vec{v}_0$, and the other endpoint at
  $$\frac{s_2 \vec{v}_1 - s_1 \vec{v}_2}{s_2 - s_1}$$
- If one of $s_0$, $s_1$, and $s_2$ has a different sign as the other two, and all three are nonzero, then the plane intersects the triangle in a line segment. Let's say that $s_0 \lt 0$, and $s_1 \gt 0$, $s_2 \gt 0$. The intersection line segment endpoints are then
  $$\frac{s_1 \vec{v}_0 - s_0 \vec{v}_1}{s_1 - s_0}$$
  and
  $$\frac{s_2 \vec{v}_0 - s_0 \vec{v}_2}{s_2 - s_0}$$

Because all vertices in a triangle are connected to all other vertices, the order in which you choose/number the vertices does not matter. For example, you can simplify the implementation of the above by sorting the three vertices so that you end up with $s_0 \le s_1 \le s_2$.